# empty String Form input in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring mvc and thymeleaf.
I am using a form which contains input fields. I would like that my controller accept empty fields. The problem that it says empty string.
I tried with this

```
 @InitBinder     
  public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {  
      binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));  
  }
```

but it doesn't work.

the html page :

```
<form th:action="@{/ajouterUniversite}" method="post" id="ajouter" style="display: none">

                                        <div>

                                            <label>nom:</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="nom" />

                                        </div>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <label>région:</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="region" />
                                        <hr/>

                                        <b>Choisir les branches dans cette université</b>
                                        <div>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                      <label><input type="checkbox" value=""    onchange="document.getElementById('math').style.display='block'"/>mathématique</label>
                                                 </div>
                                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                                      <label><input type="checkbox" value=""  onchange="document.getElementById('science').style.display='block'"/>Science</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="checkbox ">
                                                      <label><input type="checkbox" value=""  onchange="document.getElementById('info').style.display='block'" />Info</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="checkbox ">
                                                      <label><input type="checkbox" value=""  onchange="document.getElementById('lettre').style.display='block'" />Lettre</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="checkbox ">
                                                      <label><input type="checkbox" value="" onchange="document.getElementById('eco').style.display='block'" />Eco</label>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>


                                        <div id="math" style="display: none" >

                                            <label  >entrer le score du bac math :</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="scoreMath"  min="120"/>

                                        </div>
                                        <hr/>


                                        <div id="science" style="display: none" >

                                            <label  >entrer le score du bac science :</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="scoreScience" min="95"  />

                                        </div>
                                        <hr/>


                                        <div id="info" style="display: none">

                                            <label >entrer le score du bac info :</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="scoreInfo" min="65" />

                                        </div>
                                        <hr/>
                                        <div id="lettre" style="display: none">

                                            <label >entrer le score du bac lettre :</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="scoreLettre" min="50"  />

                                        </div>
                                        <hr/>

                                        <div id="eco" style="display: none">

                                            <label >entrer le score du bac eco :</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="scoreEco" min="55"  />

                                        </div>

                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

                                        </form>
```

the controller :

@Controller

```
 public class BanqueController {
    @Autowired
    private IOrient or;





     @InitBinder
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

         binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));  


        }

    @RequestMapping("/operations")
    public String index()
    {
        return "comptes";
    }





    @RequestMapping("/authentifier")    
    public String authentifier()
    {

    return "authentifier";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/pageAdmin")
    public String pageAdmin(Model model, String uname,String psw)

    {
        if  ( uname.equals("admin") && psw.equals("admin") ) return "admin";
        else
            {
            model.addAttribute("exception","vérifier les paramètres !!");
            return "authentifier";
            }



    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/ajouterUniversite",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String ajoutUniver(Model model,String nom,String region,String scoreMath,String scoreScience,String scoreEco,String scoreInfo,String scoreLettre )
    {

        model.addAttribute("ok","cv");
        Universite u=new Universite(nom,region);
        or.ajouterUniversite(nom, region, Double.parseDouble(scoreMath), Double.parseDouble(scoreScience), Double.parseDouble(scoreInfo), Double.parseDouble(scoreLettre), Double.parseDouble(scoreEco));
        return "admin";

    }
}
```

the entities:
Universite.class

```
@Entity
public class Universite implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id_universite;
    private String nom;
    private String region;
    public Universite() {
        super();
    }
    public Universite(String nom, String region) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.region = region;
    }



    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }
    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }
    public Long getId_universite() {
        return id_universite;
    }
    public void setId_universite(Long id_universite) {
        this.id_universite = id_universite;
    }



}
```

Score.java:

```
@Entity
public class Score {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long code_score;

private double scoreMath;

private double scoreScience;

private double scoreInfo;

private double scoreEco;

private double scoreLettre;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="code_universite")
private Universite universite;



public double getScoreMath() {
    return scoreMath;
}
public void setScoreMath(double scoreMath) {
    this.scoreMath = scoreMath;
}
public double getScoreScience() {
    return scoreScience;
}
public void setScoreScience(double scoreScience) {
    this.scoreScience = scoreScience;
}
public double getScoreInfo() {
    return scoreInfo;
}
public void setScoreInfo(double scoreInfo) {
    this.scoreInfo = scoreInfo;
}
public double getScoreEco() {
    return scoreEco;
}
public void setScoreEco(double scoreEco) {
    this.scoreEco = scoreEco;
}
public double getScoreLettre() {
    return scoreLettre;
}
public void setScoreLettre(double scoreLettre) {
    this.scoreLettre = scoreLettre;
}
public Universite getUniversite() {
    return universite;
}
public void setUniversite(Universite universite) {
    this.universite = universite;
}
public Score() {
    super();
}
public Score(double scoreMath, double scoreScience, double scoreInfo, double scoreEco, double scoreLettre,
        Universite universite) {
    super();
    this.scoreMath = scoreMath;
    this.scoreScience = scoreScience;
    this.scoreInfo = scoreInfo;
    this.scoreEco = scoreEco;
    this.scoreLettre = scoreLettre;
    this.universite = universite;
}
public Long getCode_score() {
    return code_score;
}
public void setCode_score(Long code_score) {
    this.code_score = code_score;
}




}
```

the error is :

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Apr 22 08:19:00 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
empty String
```

Comment: Nothing in the logs?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: Where? What line? Show full stacktrace. Or just read: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/5221149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly accessing parameters use `@RequestParam` annotation.
Read official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)

Update your method parameters to:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ajouterUniversite",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String ajoutUniver(Model model,@RequestParam(required = false) String nom,@RequestParam(required = false) String region,@RequestParam(required = false) String scoreMath, @RequestParam(required = false) String scoreScience, @RequestParam(required = false) String scoreEco, @RequestParam(required = false) String scoreInfo,@RequestParam(required = false) String scoreLettre )
    {

    model.addAttribute("ok","cv");
    Universite u=new Universite(nom,region);
    or.ajouterUniversite(nom, region, Double.parseDouble(scoreMath), Double.parseDouble(scoreScience), Double.parseDouble(scoreInfo), Double.parseDouble(scoreLettre), Double.parseDouble(scoreEco));
    return "admin";
}
```

Comment: that is my fault,the parametrs should be parsed into double.thanks